# Indexing new data while replacing old data in Elasticsearch with zero downtime

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, search-engine

I am working on Elasticsearch where I need to index the new data while replacing the old data. This replacing happens every day.

My requirement is that until the new data indexing is completed, user should be able to search from old data only. And when this indexing is completed, there should be a pointer in Elasticsearch which would just point to new indexed data in no time following with the deletion of old data. In this way I want to achieve zero downtime in this process. This indexing of data may take around 1 hour to complete.

Is there any switching concept in Elasticsearch which can handle this scenario?

Comment: This is the solution you're looking for: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html (hint: use aliases)

Answer (score 0):

[Index Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/indices-aliases.html) is what you want.